# stringer function for nested structs

Tags: go

I have two structures, one is inside of another. I want to print the inner struct with an indent to the outer one. For example, suppose this code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type inner struct {
    c int
    d int
}

func (i inner) String() string {
    out := fmt.Sprintf("c = %d\n", i.c)
    out += fmt.Sprintf("d = %d", i.d)
    return out
}

type outer struct {
    a int
    i inner
}

func (o outer) String() string {
    out := fmt.Sprintf("a = %d\n", o.a)
    out += fmt.Sprintf("\t%v", o.i)
    return out
}

func main() {
    i := inner{c: 2, d: 3}
    o := outer{a: 1, i: i}

    fmt.Println(o)
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
a = 1
    c = 2
d = 3
```

But I want:

```
a = 1
    c = 2
    d = 3
```

I know one possible solution is changing the every line of the inner struct, in the stringer of the outer struct, to start with a `\t`, but I want a cleaner solution. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `\t` from outer print

```
out += fmt.Sprintf("v", o.i)
```

And put it on the properties of the inner struct

```
out := fmt.Sprintf("c = \t%d\n", i.c)
out += fmt.Sprintf("d = \t%d", i.d)
```

Comment: You should put `\t` before `c` and `d`. This isn't what I'm looking for; I want a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner). [`bufio.NewScanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewScanner) accepts an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) instead of a `string`, but [`strings.NewReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#NewReader) can be used to transform it.

Basically, [`Scanner.Scan`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Scan) will prepare the next line, returning if there is something to consume (`false` means that either an error happened or we already consumed everything). After that you use [`Scanner.Text`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Text) or [`Scanner.Bytes`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Bytes) to get the prepared line. At the end you need to check that no error happened with [`Scanner.Err`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Err).

```
func indent(content string) (string, error) {
    out := ""
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(content))
    for scanner.Scan() {
        out += fmt.Sprintf("\t%s\n", scanner.Text())
    }
    return out, scanner.Err()
}
```

This should support multi-level embedding. You can see the usage [here](https://play.golang.org/p/nfE4oZwIuR3).